# Sort by Integer vs. by DateTime

Tags: .net, sorting, datetime, integer

I'm speaking from the .NET point of view but this could extend to other languages or frameworks that use similar logic.

Is it correct to assume that when sorting objects by a DateTime property, the DateTime value is converted to Ticks (i.e., long integers) for comparison purposes?  And as a result, the speed of sorting by `DateTime` is not much, if any, slower than sorting by integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it compares ticks. Here is actual implementation:

```
public int CompareTo(DateTime value) {
    long valueTicks = value.InternalTicks; 
    long ticks = InternalTicks; 
    if (ticks > valueTicks) return 1;
    if (ticks < valueTicks) return -1; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  So sorting by integer has no advantages.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `TicksPer constants`

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timespan-vbnet) is the link

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    ' Display these constants.
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay)
        Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.TicksPerHour)
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute)
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)
    Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output

```
864000000000
36000000000
600000000
10000000
10000
```